# Removing two nodes from a Force Layout fails while one succeeds

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to remove some nodes from a Force Layout.

The first part of the process is selecting one or more nodes. That's done with the click handler:

```
  var nodeg = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on('click', function (n) {
      if (n.dragging === true) {
        return;
      }

      // select the clicked node
      n.selected = !n.selected;

      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .ease('bounce')
        .attr('fill', getNodeBackground(n))
        .attr('transform', getNodeTransform(n));
    })
    .call(drag);
```

Note that I'm setting `selected` to true.

Next, if the user presses the `delete` key I remove the selected nodes:

```
function removeSelectedNodes() {
  if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the selected relationships?')) {
    return;
  }

  var firstIndex = -1;
  d3.selectAll('.node')
    .each(function (n, i) {
      if (n.selected !== true) {
        return;
      }

      n.data.remove = true;
      n.data.index = i;

      if (firstIndex === -1) {
        firstIndex = i;
      }
    });

  var offset = 0;
  _.each(_.where(scope.nodes, {data: {remove: true}}), function (n) {
    var removeAt = n.index;
    if (n.index > firstIndex) {
      removeAt = n.index - 1 - offset;
      offset++;
    }

    scope.nodes.splice(removeAt, 1);
    scope.links.splice(removeAt - 1, 1);
  });

  renderGraph();
}
```

The entire `renderGraph` function looks like this:

```
function renderGraph() {
  force
    .nodes(scope.nodes)
    .links(scope.links)
    .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(scope.links);
  link.exit().remove();

  link.enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(scope.nodes);
  node.exit().remove();

  var nodeg = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on('click', function (n) {
      if (n.dragging === true) {
        return;
      }

      // select the clicked node
      n.selected = !n.selected;

      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .ease('bounce')
        .attr('fill', getNodeBackground(n))
        .attr('transform', getNodeTransform(n));
    })
    .call(drag);

  nodeg.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
      return d.avatar || 'https://github.com/favicon.ico'
    })
    .attr("x", -56)
    .attr("y", -8)
    .attr("width", 64)
    .attr("height", 64);

  nodeg.append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr('class', 'name')
    .text(function (d) {
      return d.displayName;
    });

  nodeg.append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", "1.35em")
    .text(function (d) {
      return d.relationship;
    });

  force.on("tick", function () {
    link.attr("x1", function (d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
      .attr("y1", function (d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function (d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function (d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node.attr("transform", function (d) {
      return getNodeTransform(d);
    });
  });
}
```

This is where it starts going south. If I select **one node**, the graph is rendered correctly after splicing the node. However, if I remove **two nodes** the graph ends up persisting the first removed node (by index).

Let's say the first node (by index) was 'Bob' and the second node was 'Bill'. The second node will be removed, but the first one will persist. Interestingly, another one of the nodes, the current last node (by index), will be gone instead.

**NOTE:** the array looks good. The nodes I wanted removed are gone, and the remaining ones are correct.

What did I do wrong here?

**UPDATE:** I've tried **not setting** `nodes` and `links` after removing nodes, and **just** calling `start`:

```
force.start()
```

This didn't work.

Comment: what is a : Force Layout ?

Comment: @Anonymous0day it's a layout used to display connected nodes (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout).

Comment: maybe this line: `      if (n.dragging === true) { return; }` resulted in `selected` being `false`?

Comment: @paradite that line of code is to ensure that the node does not get selected if the user is just dragging the node around on the layout. That value is set during the `dragstart` and `dragend` of the `drag` behavior.

Comment: Something i don't understand, you said : > Note that I'm setting selected to true. is with that ? : `n.selected = !n.selected;` why do you use this expensive hack instead of `n.selected = true;` ?

Comment: @Anonymous0day because if they click it again it deselects the node.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Have you seen [this tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/posts/d3-force-layout-internals)? I would modify the nodes data and only then update the displayed elements.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, do you think providing a key will likely solve the problem since I am restarting the layout **and** I'm modifying the already existing `nodes` and `links` instead of building new ones? Could it just be adding a key?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud That could be it. Have you tried adding a key function?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, that's exactly what I'm going to do. I have to finalize some other changes that are in flux and then I'm going to do that. Thanks so much my friend! Really.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I would also verify that you're removing the right elements from the array. It may actually be easier to assemble a new array with the nodes you want to keep and reassign to the force layout rather than keep track of the changing indices of nodes as you remove them.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, thanks to Lars again, was to add a key function to the links and nodes:

```
  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(scope.links, function (d) {
      return d.source.data._id + '|' + d.target.data._id;
    });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(scope.nodes, function (d) {
      return d.data._id;
    });
```

Thanks Lars!